# bitcoin debug withe clion

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, debugging

I got this error when I have tried to compile on lubuntu 16.04

```
34: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘host_16bits’
inline uint16_t htole16(uint16_t host_16bits)
```

using clion, is there any guide on how to debug on linux using clion?

Answer (score 2):

CLion only supports using the CMake build system. However Bitcoin Core uses the autotools build system. Without some special configuring, it is unlikely that you will be able to build Bitcoin Core using CLion as the default CMake config will need to be modified to work with Bitcoin Core.

Instead of using CLion to build and debug it, you should be able to build Bitcoin Core in a terminal and then execute the resulting binary in CLion's debugger.